# Returning to main menu in android by a button click

Tags: android, return, program-entry-point, back, oncreate

In android, my app provides a button that the user can click to return them back to the screen that appears when the app is opened (onCreate).

How can I set that button to return the user to the main menu?

I have something like this in a switch statement (on click):

```
         case R.id.return_main:
            onCreate();
            return;
```

Where return_main is the id of the button....I know that isn't right but I couldn't think of any other way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an intent to re-launch your main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I'd have to add: Make sure you set CLEAR_TOP on the intent, or it'll only launch your home activity on *top* of your current activity (that is, without clear-top, going from B to MainActivity and then hitting "back" would still bring you back to activity B). Most uses of a "home" button imply that hitting "back" would then exit the app, which is basically what clear_top does. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29). If you are in an Activity that is a child of your main Activity, this will return you to that main Activity screen.

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You have to kill the activity to return to the Main Menu, for example I called Activity1 from Menu and kill it:

ActMenu.java

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActMenu.this,Activity1.class));
```

Activity1.java

```
Button btnForm = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnForm);      
        btnForm.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                finish();                           
            }
        });
```