# Implementing main menu link in android

Tags: android, menu, android-activity

I am developing a multilingual Android app. Here I am using typefaces for regional languages like Gujarati and Hindi. Now I want to add a Main menu link on each page except the main menu page. I learned that FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is used to clear the activity stack so the main activity is not brought on top. [HERE.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248673/returning-to-main-menu-in-android-by-a-button-click)

But when I do so it starts main menu activity again resetting language selection made by user.
Thus the language is reset to default(English in this case).

I want that the main menu activity should be brought to front by just killing other activities on the top of main activity.

I am using following code for navigation:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity1.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    finish();
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Why not save the current selected _Language_ in a `SharedPreference` file and check it when the Main Activity starts? Alternatively, you can use the `android:noHistory="true"` attribute for the Activities in the `Manifest` or the Intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` and just calling `finish()` instead of starting another Intent, which you would be clearing with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` while opening the `MainActivity1`. I am not convinced the problem lies with the `CLEAR_TOP` flag. But someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The down side of using the alternative in the earlier comment is, the activities with the android:noHistory="true" is that these activities will never be in the Activity Stack. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG%5FACTIVITY%5FNO%5FHISTORY

Comment: Does SharedPreference store user selection in persistence manner? i mean if user closes the application and relaunches it again then it will show its last selection?

Comment: Yup. SharedPreferences are stored persistently. Regardless of how many times the app is started / restarted or the device is switched off / restarted. They are always saved in the `/data/data/YOU_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs` folder.

Comment: Thats too much helpful. Thanx a lot @SiddharthLele..

Comment: Hey I tried SharedPreference and its working perfectly as I wanted. A huge thanx to you.@SiddharthLele

Comment: Glad to have have helped buddy. ;-)